# Is there any function in Echarts library that getSVG in angulajs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, svg, dom, echarts

I'm trying to getSVG of Echarts elements in angularjs , I search alot but didn’t find any useful solution. 
I need some function like I used in highchart:

```
    const chartContainerId = `#targetChart-${id}`;
        if ($(chartContainerId).highcharts()) {
            chartElementSVG = $(chartContainerId)
                .highcharts()
                .getSVG();
            $(chartContainerId).html(chartElementSVG);
        }
```

I'm using now Echart library and want to refactor this code which check if the container is Echart element then getSVG if yes. 
Any help please ..

Comment: Do you mean this lib: http://echarts.apache.org/ ? If so, then it is on canvas, therefore, can't be exported as an SVG. There is an https://echarts.apache.org/en/api.html#echartsInstance.getDom method that gets the container of the chart (if you need it).

Comment: Yes I mean this library:  echarts.apache.org 
I've already tried to use this echartsInstance.getDom  but it's not what I want, I need to get the svg of the charts

Comment: Well, as far as I see, you can't. These are different things and svg can not be retrieved from canvas directly. If you need SVG, then you should use library that builds charts with SVG.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the renderer for newer versions of eCharts to be SVG instead of canvas.

[Render by Canvas or SVG](https://echarts.apache.org/en/tutorial.html#Render%20by%20Canvas%20or%20SVG)
This would probably allow you to extract the svg more easily.

Answer (score 0):

use `ssr` option and `renderToSVGString` function

```
const echartsToSVG = Echartsjs.init(
   dom, undefined, { renderer: 'svg', ssr: true, width: 800, height: 600, }
);
echartsToSVG.setOption(data);
const svg = echartsToSVG.renderToSVGString();
```

Reference:

https://echarts.apache.org/en/api.html#echarts.init

https://echarts.apache.org/en/api.html#echartsInstance.renderToSVGString